# WooCommerce: Send mail to customer 7 days after order was marked as completed

Tags: email, woocommerce, cron

I want to send an email to all customers whose orders were marked as completed 7 days ago. The purpose is to ask if they are happy and ask them to rate the product or write a review. I want this to run as a WordPress cronjob once a day.

I've ended up with this piece of code but it's not working. I'm snot sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone please assist?

```
// Customer rate reminder email 7 days after order completed status change 

function lumiqy_send_rate_reminder_email_to_customer() {
    // Set the number of days for the interval
    $interval_days = 7;

    // Calculate the date range for 7 days ago
    $start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-{$interval_days} days"));
    $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-{$interval_days} days")) . ' 23:59:59';

    // Query for completed orders within the date range
    $completed_orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'date_completed' => '>=' . $start_date,
        'date_completed' => '<=' . $end_date,
        'status' => 'completed',
        'limit' => -1,
    ));

    // Loop through the completed orders and send email to customers
    foreach ($completed_orders as $order) {
        $customer = $order->get_user();
        $customer_email = $customer->user_email;

        // Customize the email subject and template as needed
        $subject = 'Test subject';
        $template = 'customer-rate-reminder-7-days.php';
        $bcc_email = 'mail@domain.com';

        // Send the email with BCC
        wc_mail($customer_email, $subject, '', $template, '', '', array($bcc_email));
    }
}

// Schedule the new WordPress cron job for 17:00 GMT daily
function schedule_custom_cron_job() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('lumiqy_rate_reminder_daily_cron_job')) {
        wp_schedule_event(strtotime('17:00:00'), 'daily', 'lumiqy_rate_reminder_daily_cron_job');
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'schedule_custom_cron_job');

// Hook the function to the custom WordPress cron job
add_action('lumiqy_rate_reminder_daily_cron_job', 'lumiqy_send_rate_reminder_email_to_customer');
```

Comment: Better use **[Action Scheduler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/action-scheduler/)** plugin which is a scalable, traceable job queue for background processing…
Note that [Action Scheduler library](https://github.com/woocommerce/action-scheduler) is included / used by * WooCommerce and WooCommerce Subscriptions. 
The documentations is on [ActionScheduler.org](https://actionscheduler.org/).

Comment: Which part its not working ? You need to debug first is there any orders to sent reminder. After that is the cron job executed. Keep in mind if site is not active at the cron job time it wont execute it. What i use to do is to create cron job from my hosting that will trigger the wp cron jobs.